# Critical Points of the Length Functional

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, arc-length

I am tasked with finding the critical points of the following length functional $$ L(\lambda) = \int_{I} ||\lambda^{'}||dt$$ My guess would be to solve the Euler-Lagrange Equations. In doing so we would end up with a system of ODEs (perhaps just 1) and the solution to those equations are the critical points of L($\lambda)$. Is this correct or am I on the wrong path entirely?

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe write $|| \lambda ' || = \sqrt{\lambda'.\lambda'}$ then apply the calculus of variations.

Comment: The length function is a pain because of the square root,  but the squared-length functional behaves rather more nicely, and they have the same critical points, if I'm remembering correctly. Milnor's *Morse Theory* works this out quite nicely.

Comment: Whewn you say apply thr calculus of variations, what exactly do you mean @KennyWong? Do you mean add the extra term so that we'd have $\lambda (t + \eta*s)$ with s ranging from 0 to 1 and then.. do what? Or do you mean just use the Euler-Lagrange equations? In which case I don't even think we need to add the variation term

Comment: @JohnHughes Do you remember which section treats the squared length functional? I'm looking through the book now but it's rather dense and I'm unsure where exactly it is.

Comment: It's in a later chapter whose name says something about geodesics, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining an ODE by calculus of variations isn't too bad! The length of the curve is:
$$ L(\lambda) = \int_I \left( \sum_i \dot \lambda_i \dot \lambda_i \right)^{\frac 1 2} dt$$
where the $i$-index is a coordinate index.

The Euler-Lagrange equations say
$$ \frac{\delta L}{\delta \lambda_i} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\delta L}{\delta \dot \lambda_i}\right)$$
for each $i$, i.e.
$$0 = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\dot \lambda_i}{\left( \sum_{j}\dot \lambda_j \dot \lambda_j \right)^{\frac 1 2}}\right)$$

---

This also works if you introduce a Riemannian metric $g_{ij}(\lambda)$:
$$ L(\lambda) = \int_I \left( \sum_{ij} g_{ij}(\lambda) \dot \lambda_i \dot \lambda_j \right)^{\frac 1 2} dt$$

The Euler-Lagrange equations now say (for each $i$):
$$ \frac{ \sum_{jk} \partial_i g_{jk}(\lambda) \dot \lambda_j \dot \lambda_k}{2 \left( \sum_{jk} g_{jk}(\lambda) \dot \lambda_j \dot \lambda_k \right)^{\frac 1 2}} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{ \sum_j g_{ij}(\lambda) \dot \lambda_j}{\left( \sum_{jk} g_{jk}(\lambda) \dot \lambda_j \dot \lambda_k \right)^{\frac 1 2}} \right)$$

Note that if we choose the parameter $t$ so that the curve $\lambda(t)$ is of unit velocity, i.e. if we choose $t$ so that $\sum_{ij} g_{ij}(\lambda) \dot \lambda_i \dot \lambda_j = 1$ everywhere, then this reduces to
$$ \ddot \lambda_i + \frac 1 2 \sum_{jkl}(g^{-1})^{il} \left( \partial_j g_{lk} + \partial_k g_{jl} - \partial_l g_{jk}\right)\dot \lambda_j \dot \lambda_k = 0.$$
And this is the geodesic equation! So it's not so bad after all.